# trigger fancybox iframe without click but when a condition is met

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-2

Simple question, I dont think its possible but hopefully someone can proof me wrong.

Is it possible to trigger fancybox without a click but rather if an event is met

**Example**

```
if(balance<1){
#fancyBoxOpen
}
else{
Continue to page
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

You could create a function that triggers fancybox like :

```
var triggerFancybox = function () {
    var content = "Sorry, the balance is less than 1";
    jQuery.fancybox.open(content);
}
```

And call that function when your condition is met like :

```
if (balance < 1) {
    triggerFancybox();
}
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/55fg5h6t/)**

.... or [another](http://jsfiddle.net/55fg5h6t/1) with a hard-coded condtion